# How to extract a SharePoint list items into GridView

Tags: sharepoint-2007

I need to extract the data from a SharePoint List and view it in a GridView ASP control or any other data table control, how to use the SharePoint API to extract the items from the SharePiont list and demonstrated in a ASP control

Answer (score 0):

There are 2 options:

- Using the SharePoint object model, but that is **only useable if you are on the same server** as sharepoint is.
  Generally you would use the SPList object's GetItems method, which takes an SPQuery, that in turn uses a CAML query to specify exactly which items you want returned, i.e. akin to a SQL SELECT statement. for more info check out the [SPList.GetItems(SPquery) article on MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx)
- The other option is to use the Lists.asmx Web Service to query a list. The web service can be called from another machine. For more info check the [MSDN article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/lists.lists.getlistitems.aspx)